# Extend 2 lambda with different signature in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin we can't create class which implements 2 lambdas with different signature, like this:

```
class Test<T> : (T) -> Unit, () -> T {
    ...
}
```

which gives following error:

> Type parameter R of 'Function' has inconsistent values: Unit, T

I understand the reason why it happens: all lambdas are `FunctionN` interfaces and all `FunctionN` interfaces extend some marker interface called `Function` which can't be invoked. But also last one is the root cause of generics conflict and error mentioned above.

My question probably to Kotlin team: is there any reason why all `FunctionN` extend `Function` interface? Maybe some internal/bytecode stuff which isn't obvious for us, but makes some tricky optimization for performance underneath.

Comment: maybe you want to ask this question on https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/ and cross-link both?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/function-types.md gives some limited information about the use of `Function`:

> - Introduce a physical class `Function` and unlimited number of fictitious (synthetic) classes `Function0`, `Function1`, ... in the compiler front-end
> - Provide a way to get arity of an arbitrary `Function` object (pretty straightforward).
> - Hack `is/as Function5` on any numbered function in codegen (and probably `KClass.cast()` in reflection) to check against `Function` and its arity.

(note: the fictitious `Function*` classes are in `kotlin` package, `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function*` interfaces are real.)

The problems this approach fixes are listed in the Goals section:

> - Get rid of 23 hardwired physical function classes. One of the problems with them is that they should be effectively duplicated in reflection which means a lot of physical classes in kotlin-runtime.jar.
> - Make extension functions assignable to normal functions (and vice versa), so that it's possible to do `listOfStrings.map(String::length)`
> - Allow functions with more than 23 parameters, theoretically any number of parameters (in practice 255 on JVM).
> - At the same time, allow implementing Kotlin functions easily from Java: `new Function2() { ... }` and overriding `invoke` only would be the best. Enabling SAM conversions on Java 8 would also be terrific.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply overload invoke method manually to get the behavior of lamdbas:

```
class Test<T> {
    operator fun invoke(p1: T) {
    }

    operator fun invoke(): T {
        return ...
    }
}
```

To contact the Kotlin's team you can find them on the forum (https://discuss.kotlinlang.org), or file an issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).